# how to display error message on validation fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use Mailchimp v3, and I want to display an error when someone enter wrong input.

This system is under ajax. How to display that ?
I use this class : https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api
Thank you.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(\'#signup\').submit(function() {
    $("#message").html("<div class=\"alert alert-info\" style=\"padding:05px; margin-top:5px;\" role=\"alert\">' . MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_MAILCHIMP_SUBMIT_MESSAGE . '</div>");
    $.ajax({
      url: \'ext/api/mailchimp_v3/subscribe.php\', // proper url to your "store-address.php" file
      type: \'POST\', // <- IMPORTANT
      data: $(\'#signup\').serialize() + \'&ajax=true\',
      success: function(msg) {
        $(\'#fname\').val(""); // reset input field
        $(\'#lname\').val(""); // reset input field
        $(\'#email\').val(""); // reset input field
        $(\'#message\').html(\'<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissible\" role=\"alert\"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' . MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_MAILCHIMP_SUCCESS_MESSAGE . '</div>\'); // display the message
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>';
```

Comment: do you mean when someone enter wrong input you want to display an error ?

Comment: yes, if there is an error, a message appear under the submit button. Currently, just email adding message is displayed

Comment: i edit your question so it will be easier for people to understand and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the error block below the success block

```
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
      // display the error message
  }
```

Comment: Tk, no, it does'nt work, the page is refreshed with this approach.